# Not reading the content of files in wpf

Tags: c#, file, fileinfo, directoryinfo

```
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
        foreach (FileInfo flInfo in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            String name = flInfo.Name;
            long size = flInfo.Length;
            DateTime creationTime = flInfo.CreationTime;
            const int counter = 0;
            int count = counter + 1;
        }
```

I am getting the  path but not not reading the content and file info

Comment: How about adding File.ReadAllText(flInfo.Name) ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

Comment: don't know how this is related with WPF

Comment: THe usual way. "It is related to WPF ins the way that hte poster has no clue what he is doing". As such, he does not understand what WPF actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I do not understand, why you need counter variable
2. You do not try read the content. 
   If you want read the file, use stream to read it:

   ```
   using (StreamReader reader = flInfo.OpenText())
   {
   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi zzfima i added counter to check whether file is reading or not. i want to read all the files in a directory not a single file can you modify your code and add it pplease. I was not getting the files from the directory not the file reading problem

Comment: You do not increase "counter" variable (at least in current peace of code), pay attention. So, your problem is getting files from directory?

Comment: please leave the counter issue it is not the problem. I was not getting the content to read